# Can twisted.names.client be forced to return ipv4 addresses? (without modifying resolv.conf or ETH devices)

Tags: dns, twisted, ipv4, names

The problem I'm running into is that because IPv6 is enabled on my ethernet interface - so hostname resolution sometimes yields IPv6 results when I don't want them.

Is it possible to get twisted.names.client to **only** return ipv4 addresses without making any changes to the operating system / name resolution / ethernet configuration?

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
from twisted.names import client

def got_arg(*args):
    print 'got_arg',args

def get_arg(arg):
    d = client.getHostByName('www.google.com').addCallback(got_arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_arg('www.google.com')
    reactor.run()
```

This code *always* gives me an ipv6 addr on my Linux box:

```
got_arg ('2001:4860:4001:800::1010',)
```

I'd love to be able to force ipv4 lookups without having to modify anything underneath. Any ideas? For lack of forcing, at least having a dict or tuple with the results broken up by ipv4/ipv6 would be nice.

Comment: IPv4 (A) or IPv6 (AAAA) records may be returned whether or not you have an interface with an IPv6 address assigned.  Twisted Names just gives you back results from the nameserver you query.  Nameservers generally won't change their response based on what your address is.  So this is a more general problem to solve, not just one that applies to people with IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out.. You have to use client.lookupAllRecords and then test the type of records returned..

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
from twisted.names import client, dns

def got_arg(*args):
    for a in args[0][0]:
        if a.payload.TYPE == dns.A:
            print 'A    - ipv4',a.payload
        elif a.payload.TYPE == dns.AAAA:
            print 'AAAA - ipv6',a.payload


def get_arg(arg):
    d = client.lookupAllRecords('www.google.com').addCallback(got_arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_arg('www.google.com')
    reactor.run()
```

**EDIT**

I realize this solution is insufficient - specifically in the case where the first batch of records only contains a single CNAME pointing to another address..

The reason for this is that the twisted.names.common.extractRecord() looks first for ipv6 addresses and immediately returns them - with no obvious mechanism to override this behavior.

So, I put together a hacky solution for this so that we don't even try to resolve down the chain on ipv6 addresses by making an ugly monkey patch..

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
from twisted.names import dns
from twisted.names import common

def myExtractRecord(resolver, name, answers, level=10):
    if not level:
        return None
    for r in answers:
        if r.name == name and r.type == dns.A:
            return socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET, r.payload.address)
    for r in answers:
        if r.name == name and r.type == dns.CNAME:
            result = myExtractRecord(
                resolver, r.payload.name, answers, level - 1)
            if not result:
                return resolver.getHostByName(
                    str(r.payload.name), effort=level - 1)
            return result
    # No answers, but maybe there's a hint at who we should be asking about
    # this
    for r in answers:
        if r.type == dns.NS:
            from twisted.names import client
            r = client.Resolver(servers=[(str(r.payload.name), dns.PORT)])
            return r.lookupAddress(str(name)
                ).addCallback(
                    lambda (ans, auth, add):
                        myExtractRecord(r, name, ans + auth + add, level - 1))

common.extractRecord = myExtractRecord
```

I put that in dnsclient.py and use it in my main prog by:

```
from twisted.names import client
import dnsclient
```

If there's a more elegant solution for this, I'm all ears. I think this would be more friendly if getHostByName accepted a mask of dns.A,dns.AAAA,dns.A && dns.AAAA for figuring out which records to walk the tree of.